# Apply Microsoft Authenticator App to approve/deny 2FA in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, two-factor-authentication, authenticator

Currently, when we use Microsoft Authenticator App with Microsoft account, they ask us to click approve or deny instead of filling in the passcode into logging website, system.

Can we apply the same experience into our website without Microsoft account such as  individual account or organizational account?

I suppose if it can, Microsoft will ask us to register an api to let them upon users approve,deny.

If it cannot, is there any alternative apps, services provide this?

PS: of course we can implement by ourselves mobile app acts as an authenticator app

Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can achieve this effect using the [Authy push notification API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/authy/api/push-authentications) along with your users using the [Authy application](https://authy.com/features/). This method can also fall back to using an in app code or SMS based 2FA too.

Comment: Twilio has stopped the Authy push notification API, with no replacement scheduled.

Comment: The Authy push notification API is deprecated, indeed. The replacement at this point involves [embedding the Twilio Verify SDK into your own mobile application and using Verify Push](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/push).

Comment: — But the Authy application doesn't support Verify Push (it's supposedly coming but your support says they have no timeline). Verify Push is only useful at the moment if I'm writing my own mobile app as I understand it.

Comment: That is correct. This is an answer from 2019 though. I also no longer work at Twilio, after their layoffs last year, so I have no further insight into when that feature may be coming to the API.